# How to close TextBox Menu Item properly on KeyPress

Tags: c#, winforms, visibility, menuitem, toolstrip

I am using radial gauges to display temperatures. The user should be able to rename each gauge, which isn't possible by double-clicking on the name, so I have to make a menu where user can change the names of the gauges.

I solved this by making a menu item for every gauge. So when you click on a menuitem, for example "Thermometer 1", a sub menu of type `ToolStripTextBox` will appear containing the same text in a `TextBox`. In that `TextBox` the user can change the name. I want when the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in `TextBox` the textbox menu item get closed, but the parent menu item "Theremometer1" stay open. (Thermometer1, Thermometer2, ... shooul not disappear after closing the textbox menu item.)

Here is the code I use to close that `TextBox` menu:

```
private void thermometer1ToolStripMenuItem1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
    {
        thermometer1ToolStripMenuItem1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

But as you can see small white bar stays visible. Can someone help me please?

How can I close that `ToolStripTextBox` menu item properly when the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd>? That small white bar should not remain visible.

[image: The Menuitems]

[image: The small white bar]

Comment: _"I want that when you press enter that the Textbox will disappear"_ - that's exactly what's happening, so what's your question? Do you instead want all menus to close, or some of them?

Comment: The white bar is the Problem

Comment: see if refreshing the `Form` fixes the prob or not. `this.Refresh();`

Comment: The white bar is a menu without any items shown. What _exactly_ do you want to happen?

Comment: that the complete menuitem dissappears that you can see in the first picture at the right side where the TextBox with the Text "Thermometer 1" is, so not only the TextBox should disappear but the whole MenuItem

Comment: @The5thBluesky What CodeCaster is telling you is that the whole MenuItem *did* disappear. What you're seeing isn't the MenuItem. What you're seeing is a submenu that does not have any MenuItems in it. You say you want the MenuItem to disappear. It did. If the result isn't what you want, but is exactly what you asked for, try to give a better description of the result you want. Being as precise as possible in your English description will generally help translate to code.

Comment: @hvd Its completely clear what the OP is asking. When all items of an open dropdown are removed, the dropdown remains open containing no items. It's an unexpected/undesirebale behavior. It only occurs  for an open dropdown. The problem needs a [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426080/set-menuitem-visible-false-leaves-small-white-bar-visible/38426500#38426500).

Comment: @RezaAghaei It may be completely clear to you and me what's going on, but based on the OP's wording, it apparently is not to the OP. Trying to get the OP to understand the OP's own problem is a good thing, in my opinion.

Comment: @hvd Your idea is completely OK. But sometimes such comments like *What exactly do you want to happen?*  or *try to give a better description of the result you want* (specially by experienced users like you) may encourage users to vote for closing the question or downvote it. While I believe the question is good enough, and also we have the same opinion that it's clear what the OP is asking :)

Comment: first thanks for the comments i´m sorry if the question isn´t good enough. If it is a submenu how can i close it?

Comment: @hvd I realized that the actual question of the OP need *to give a better description*. It *seems* he wants to  know the right way to close the menu. Sometimes I see comments from experienced users which cause downvotes and close the questions while the question is not a bad question. When a question closes it's hard top reopen it, even after editing and making it more clear, I just tried to avoid such problem. So instead of downvote and close vote I prefer to ask question to make it more clear. Hope my previous comment didn't offend you and hope there isn't any misunderstanding between us :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Don't worry, I don't see any reason why I or anyone else should get offended by your comments. And given that this question did show good faith effort by the OP, downvoting seems very much inappropriate and I'm happy to see that no one did so. As for voting to close, I didn't, but I see that as a judgement call here. Given that the OP got a useful answer already, the unclear wording makes it unlikely that someone else with the same problem manages to find this question (I'm not putting blame here), and the closed question doesn't count against the OP, I think it's okay to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Right way to Close a Dropdown**

Setting `Visible` of the item is not what you need. When you want to close a menu item, it's enough to find it's owner which is [`ToolStripDropDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown(v=vs.110).aspx) and call its `Close` method:

```
private void someToolStripMenuItem_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        var item = (ToolStripItem)sender;
        var owner = (ToolStripDropDown)(item.Owner);
        owner.Close();
    }
}
```

This way you will not face with that small white bar problem, because you close the dropdown. But when instead of closing the dropdown you set the visible of item to `false`, the dropdown is still open, not containing an element, so it shows as small white bar.

**What's the Small Bar Issue?**

The small white bar which you see is an open [`ToolStripDropDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown(v=vs.110).aspx) containing no item as mentioned above.

This only occurs when you remove all items of a dropdown while the dropdown is open; in this case the dropdown stays open containing no items. As soon as you close the dropdown, it disappears and will not appear by pointing to its parent.

If you make all items of a closed dropdown invisible, the dropdown will not appear by pointing to its parent. This behavior is also desired for an open dropdown and the problem needs a workaround.

You can check if the owner of the item which you made invisible contains no other visible items, then make it also invisible. The owner of the item is that dropdown which stays open.

```
private void someToolStripMenuItem_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        var item = (ToolStripItem)sender;
        item.Visible = false;
        var owner = (ToolStrip)(item.Owner);
        owner.Visible = owner.Items.Cast<ToolStripItem>().Any(x => x.Visible);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the first method is the answer of your question and surely it will not make Thermometer1, Theremometer2 invisible. Just use a clean sample code and attach this event handler `someToolStripMenuItem_KeyPress` only to keypress of the menu that contains textbox. Then after pressing enter in textbox, the textbox menu will be closed.

Comment: if i make a clean sample code it works but not in my other code -.-

Comment: It means my answer is correct :) The purpose of this topic is solving the current problem and shows you how to properly close a menu. For other problems, ask new questions and keep this question specific to a single topic.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for the answer and help

Comment: thank you and i accepted the answer :D

Comment: I know now why it closed the whole Menu and not only the toolstrip cause i inherit Form from "MetroForm" to have a Metro-Style GUI when i make it to a normal Form the Method functioned -.-

Comment: no we don´t. I don´t like the normal WindowsForms Style but as it is i have to use the normal style

Comment: You can start learning Universal Widows Apps or use a stable 3rd party component set or try to create your own components.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to delete the sub-item and not make it visible or not.
I believe your problem is related to have an "invisible" child from Thermometer1.
Try to delete the child item.

Comment: but when i delete the child item i couldn´t change the name anymore during that runtime, can i?

Comment: No, you won't. But neither if it is not visible anymore...  It's an error of logic so...